# Can I make an interactive filter in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am using SQL in DashBuilder and want to make a statement in SQL that will display one column of data (month). Then when the user clicks on a row in that column of data that table will display the rest of the columns filtered on that entry (a specific month) to only show data from that month. Is this possible in SQL?

I can filter in SQL without a problem but am unsure if interactive filtering is possible or if I need to use another feature of DashBuilder to do so.